# What is the geometric intuition for the sheaf-theoretic terms "soft", "fine", and "flabby"?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, soft-question, ho.history-overview, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

The sheaf-theoretic terms "soft", "flabby", and "fine" are of an obviously geometric character, and suggest opposition with "hard", "rigid", and "coarse" sheaves (I'm just inventing these terms here).

My rough "intuition by opposition" for soft sheaves is that the sheaf of smooth functions on a manifold is soft since every germ can be extended to a global smooth function, whereas the sheaf of holomorphic functions on a complex manifold obviously fails to be soft, and is thus "hard" in some sense. But I still don't really see what mental imagery the term "soft" is supposed to evoke.

Since these terms most likely originated in algebraic geometry, I am curious what sort of geometric ideas they are supposed to capture?  I personally work in the $C^\infty$-differentiable side of geometry, so my mental library consists largely of locally constant or soft sheaves, and I'm less familiar with the algebro-geometric content that likely inspired these terms.

Comment: The word soft invokes malleability which $C^\infty$ functions definitely are, say, compared to analytic functions or polynomials.

Comment: I always imagined that "flabby" sheaves are named that way, because they are "fat" in the sense that they have lots of sections. In fact, more than what you could expect from an everyday sheaf. (The condition is that any section from any open set can be extended to any containing open set). So, I would say that the opposite would be "thin". Then you could ask what "thin" sheaves are. A couple of candidates could be constant sheaves and skyscraper sheaves.

Comment: @SándorKovács I actually paired (soft vs. hard), (flabby vs. rigid), and (fine vs. course). But anyway I think your interpretation of flabby is probably the intended one.

Comment: @Ravi I think your interpretation of softness also sounds reasonable.